# Wladimir's new GPG key

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core-development, authentication

I just went to install the latest version of bitcoind and discovered that Wladimir has signed the https://bitcoin.org/bin/bitcoin-core-0.12.1/SHA256SUMS.asc file with a new GPG key: https://bitcoin.org/laanwj-releases.asc. His previous key was https://bitcoin.org/laanwj.asc.

Some Googling turned up [this notice on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/bitcoin_devlist/comments/3bsw31/new_gpg_signing_key_for_bitcoin_core_binary/) but he doesn't say why he started using a new key. Does anybody know why he switched keys? Are there any good reasons to switch keys? Should I be worried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I chatted to Wladimir about this. He hasn't switched to a new key, he's just using a separate key to sign binary releases.

Additionally, he has signed the new key with the old key, so there's an audit path.

Comment: any idea why he's using a different key to sign the binaries?

Comment: Separation of responsibilities - if one is compromised it does not compromise the other, and it can be revoked without affecting the other.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe he is worried his old key was compromised somehow? If that is the case I would be careful about trusting anything signed with the old GPG key after the soonest date it could have been compromised.

I don't see a reason to worry about future releases he signs with his new GPG key.

Comment: in the reddit notice he says he is continuing to use his old key to sign git commits, so he must still trust it.